# Aspx grid view FileUpload

Tags: asp.net-3.5, devexpress

**Bllow is my AspxGridview syntax**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="Menu_ID"
                OnCellEditorInitialize="ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize" OnCustomUnboundColumnData="ASPxGridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                        <EditButton Visible="True">
                        </EditButton>
                        <NewButton Visible="True">
                        </NewButton>
                        <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                        </DeleteButton>
                        <CustomButtons>
                            <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton Text="Create a Copy" ID="Copy" />
                        </CustomButtons>
                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Module_ID" FieldName="Module_ID" UnboundType="Integer"
                        VisibleIndex="1">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn Caption="Target_URL" FieldName="Target_URL" UnboundType="String"
                        VisibleIndex="2">
                        <PropertiesButtonEdit>
                            <Buttons>
                                <dx:EditButton Text=".." Width="5px">
                                </dx:EditButton>
                            </Buttons>
                        </PropertiesButtonEdit>
                    </dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Menu_ID" FieldName="Menu_ID" UnboundType="Integer"
                        VisibleIndex="3">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

AspxGridview **edit/insert mode** Click on **Target_URL** column button i want to FileUpload .

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following example posted in our site:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E95